# Are RISC-V instruction execution durations standardized for the sake of cryptographic security?

Tags: security, assembly, cryptography, timing, riscv

Some cryptographic functions require a consistent execution duration to avoid timing attacks. I read that such functions targeting x86 are hard to write for reasons potentially including the emulated nature of the ISA and out-of-order processing. Therefore preventing timing attacks on the x86 is not easy because it depends on complex, and/or unknown factors in any given moment.

In a standard RISC-V core, are instruction timings predictably consistent relative to each another? What about in the case of a standard core with out-of-order processing or proprietary implementations of the base ISA?

Comment: What cryptographic library implementation takes this into consideration?

Comment: +1 but questions to the "RISC-V" team are of course not on topic here, so I removed the last question. Please don't be an arse and do the capitalization of your question yourself, this is not utube.

Comment: @user2548418: Well written password hash comparison libraries and rsa encryption libraries are likely to take timing attacks into account. I don't know which those are, but maintainers of such libraries should know the answer to that question. Other timing attacks and [side channel attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_channel_attack) may also be worthy of investigation.

Answer (score 4):

RISC-V could be implemented in a machine with deterministic latencies; this has to do more with the implementation than the ISA.

See this project for a RISC-V implementation that supports predictable-latency execution: https://github.com/pretis/flexpret.  It was developed for the embedded space, but would seem to be suitable for your proposed application as well.

Comment: Is cache-miss latency predictable for the flexpret?

Answer (score 3):

It is important differentiate an ISA from an implementation of it. Nothing in the RISC-V spec mandates the instruction execution latencies. Most implementations will do whatever gives them the highest performance. A security paranoid processor could be designed to have consistent latencies for all instructions and yet still conform to the RISC-V spec.

A nice feature of RISC-V is that plenty of opcode space was intentionally left unused to make room for ISA extensions. There appear to be no publicly announced plans for a crypto extension, so this feature could be incorporated into a crypto extension when it is made if needed.

Comment: can you clarify how such "consistently timed" instructions would work in the presence of caches? Would a requirement of their use be that memory is first loaded into a scratchpad memory? Would memory be stalled to the worst case every access? Would the guarantee only apply to non-memory ops?

Comment: I'm not sure, I'm also not advocating for consistent latencies. I just wanted to point out that when designing an extension, the designer can include what features they want. I find the notion of depending on certain latencies to be a bit too complicated of a HW/SW interface to support over a range of processors/generations and somewhat reminiscent of VLIW.

Comment: @Chris: You'd only need constant-latency loads if you had data-dependent memory access.  Normally crypto code just avoids doing that, so all that matters is that shifts, adds, xors, etc. have the same performance regardless of data.  (Which is of course trivial for a normal CPU with most instructions; usually only division and sqrt are data-dependent.  And sometimes multiply on CPUs with slow multiply.)  e.g. when comparing two strings, `diff |= s1[i] ^ s2[i]` with no early-out on the first difference.  Yes you access memory, but the timing difference didn't depend on data.

Comment: (Crypto code that needs lookup tables depending on the data has a much harder time of things, and may need special HW support, or clunky coding techniques.)

Answer (score 1):

> "is there a standard for how long each instruction should take to complete relative to other operations?"

No.

Such behavior will be consistent with all other major ISAs as far as I am aware of.

An out-of-order processor will execute instructions as their dependencies resolve. Cache misses and the potentially random nature of issue select will mean that successive loop iterations will behave differently with regards to when instructions execute relative to one another. Any number of other micro-architecture issues get in the way, including instruction fetch misses, dcache misses, resource stalls causing replays, etc. Even a typical in-order core will face such issues.

> how does the RISC-V team plan to address potential standard or non-standard complexity that a cryptographic library developer must find some way to address?

I can't speak for the RISC-V team, but if I may hazard a guess, I suspect that this (and similar) areas will involve the wider community to discuss and address such issues.

Comment: I've removed the last part of the question, I don't think it is on topic here; as you said: we don't know.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about core, but I've read that in *RISC-V Cryptography Extensions Volume I* (`riscv-crypto-spec-scalar-v1.0.1.pdf`), cryptographic instructions are required of this:

> This instruction must always be implemented such that its execution latency does not depend on the data being operated on.

So in the context of cryptographic-specific instructions, yes.